When is ANTLR skip applied?
Does ANTLR wait to find the longest string that matches a token that should be skipped or it skips it as soon as it matches that token?
Suppose we have two tokens in our grammar like this:
TEST:
    [\n][\t | '    ']'|'
    ;
WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;

and the input is like this:

    |

i expected it to be matched by TEST token but it seems like that the first part is matched by WS and then it's skipped so the output says
token recognition error at: '| '

can you explain this and What should i do to be able to catch TEST token in my input?

skip has zero effect on the matching procedure: (1) match the lexer rule with the longest string first; (2) if two or more lexer rules match the string with the same length, pick the first matching rule. After a match is found, the lexer will either assign a token type and channel to the token, or in the case of "skip", the lexer will skip creation of a token, and continues with lexing after the string matched. The expression [\t | '    '] is completely wrong. You want ('\t' | '    '), not a char set of tab, space, |, .... Look at the warning messages from the Antlr tool.

You're right about ('\t' | '    ') but it still gives the same output.

Check your newline terminators. I tested the updated grammar (grammar foo; TEST: [\n] ( '\t' | '    ' ) '|' ; WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; start: .* EOF;), and it works fine. But the parser only works for Unix line translations. Perform an od -t x1 -t c of your input. If you are on Windows, install Cygwin because cmd.exe and pwsh.exe are terrible. You could also change the grammar to recognize \r.

I think there are some decision in your exampke, which must be hanndle by grammar not the lexer. I suggest the following apporoach:
grammar Simple;

// Lexer rules
WS          : [ \t]+ -> skip;  // Skip general whitespace and tabs
EMPTY_LINE 

 : NEWLINE -> skip; // Skip empty lines
NEWLINE     : '\r'? '\n';      // Newline characters
FOUR_SPACES : '    ';          // Four spaces
TAB         : '\t';            // Tab character
A_LETTER    : 'A';             // The letter A

// Parser rules
file        : indentedLine EOF;

indentedLine: (FOUR_SPACES | TAB) A_LETTER NEWLINE;


The grammar is wrong. EMPTY_LINE references NEWLINE and EMPTY_LINE is marked "skip". So you will never see a NEWLINE in the token stream. Further, for a \t (tab) in the input, WS always matches. TAB cannot ever match.  The same for FOUR_SPACES. The use of TAB NEWLINE FOUR_SPACES in a parser rule cannot work. The Antlr parser does not "guide" how tokens are matched. Antlr lexers follow two simple rules: (1) Match the longest string. (2) If two or more lexer rules match the same string, the first one always "wins." It is impossible for indentedLine to ever match.
